# Разделение информации в файле на столбцы

Tags: python, dataframe

У меня есть файлы с численными данными. Но числа разделены пробелом. Из за этого когда я строю датафрэйм все числа находится в одном столбце. Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете использовать при вызове [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) параметр `delim_whitespace=True` или, что тоже самое, параметр `sep='\s+'`